# How to parse CSSStyleSheet object into a valid css?

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

I've been playing with document.styleSheets API and it mostly does what I want, but once I add a bunch of rules I want to be able to parse the shylesheet object into a valid css (so I can put it into a downloadable file), is possible with the API or just by manually looping trough it?

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/documentation.html Try this

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over it:

```
var rules = [], i, j, css;

for (i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[i].rules.length; j++) {
        rules.push(document.styleSheets[i].rules[j].cssText);
    }
}

css = rules.join('\n');
console.log(css);
```

Comment: Is there an efficient way to output all styles under same selector, for example if I have rule1: header { color:red }, rule2: header { padding: 0 }, in the parsed file it would output: header {color:red; padding: 0}